# Styling selected objects with SLD

Tags: geoserver, sld

Does anyone knows - is it possible to style selected objects in Geoserver (using SLD) in different way than "normal" objects? For example: "normal" points from layer would be shown in blue, but selected (by clicking, queries etc.) in red. 
I have searched through in Geoserver docs, SLD specification etc., but without satisfactory result.
The only traces of what I need can be found in "Definition and Implementation of an Active Web Map Service" article (by Nieves R. Brisaboa, Antonio Fariña, Miguel R. Luaces, David Trillo and Jose R.Viqueira).
I think that mentioned styling is not possible yet. Maybe CSS would help?

Comment: have you look into generating new styling and sending it via the SLD_BODY parameter? if a query should set all type=selected in red, then you should be able to define a new sld document and send it to geoserver.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you draw a second layer over the top of the map with a different style and a filter that makes your selection specified in the CQL filter that goes with the selection layer.